# How to calculate an epipolar line with a stereo pair of images in Python OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, stereo-3d, pose-estimation

How can I take two images of an object from different angles and draw epipolar lines on one based on points from the other?

For example, I would like to be able to select a point on the left picture using a mouse, mark the point with a circle, and then draw an epipolar line on the right image corresponding to the marked point.

I have 2 XML files which contain a 3x3 camera matrix and a list of 3x4 projection matrices for each picture. The camera matrix is `K`. The projection matrix for the left picture is `P_left`. The projection matrix for the right picture is `P_right`.

I have tried this approach:

1. Choose a pixel coordinate (x,y) in the left image (via mouse click)
2. Calculate a point `p` in the left image with `K^-1 * (x,y,1)`
3. Calulate the pseudo inverse matrix `P+` of `P_left` (using `np.linalg.pinv`)
4. Calculate the epipole `e'` of the right image: `P_right * (0,0,0,1)`
5. Calculate the skew symmetric matrix `e'_skew` of `e'`
6. Calculate the Fundamental matrix `F`: `e'_skew * P_right * P+`
7. Calculate the epipolar line `l'` on the right image: `F * p`
8. Calculate a point `p'` in the right image: `P_right * P+ * p`
9. Transform `p'` and `l` back to pixel coordinates
10. Draw a line using `cv2.line` through `p'` and `l`

Comment: You're on the right line, I highly recommend reading this https://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/hzbook/hzbook1/HZepipolar.pdf

Comment: @Oliver9523 so is it okay so far how i calculated p and p'? because so far i see no line what so ever on my images

Comment: I'm not sure what you're calculating in step 4.
You can check that two corresponding points satisfy (x'^t)Fx = 0 (page 226 on the above link). Also, try calculating it by hand just to ensure you are using the correct values, it makes it easier to spot any numerical errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just did this a few days ago and it works just fine. Here's the method I used:

1. Calibrate camera(s) to obtain camera matricies and distortion matricies (Using openCV `getCorners` and `calibrateCamera`, you can find lots of tutorials on this, but it sounds like you already have this info)
2. Perform stereo calibration with openCV `stereoCalibrate()`. It takes as parameters all of the camera and distortion matricies. You need this to determine the correlation between the two visual fields. You will get back several matricies, the rotation matrix R, translation vector T, essential matrix E and fundamental matrix F.
3. You then want to do undistortion using openCV `getOptimalNewCameraMatrix` and `undistort()`. This will get rid of a lot of camera aberrations (it will give you better results)
4. Finally, use openCV's `computeCorrespondEpilines` to calculate the lines and plot them. I will include some code below you can try out in Python. When I run it, I can get images like this (The colored points have their corresponding epilines drawn in the other image)

[image: Epiline Calculation]
Heres some code (Python 3.0). It uses two static images and static points, but you could easily select the points with the cursor. You can also refer to the OpenCV docs on calibration and stereo calibration [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html).

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# find object corners from chessboard pattern  and create a correlation with image corners
def getCorners(images, chessboard_size, show=True):
    criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)

    # prepare object points, like (0,0,0), (1,0,0), (2,0,0) ....,(6,5,0)
    objp = np.zeros((chessboard_size[1] * chessboard_size[0], 3), np.float32)
    objp[:, :2] = np.mgrid[0:chessboard_size[0], 0:chessboard_size[1]].T.reshape(-1, 2)*3.88 # multiply by 3.88 for large chessboard squares

    # Arrays to store object points and image points from all the images.
    objpoints = [] # 3d point in real world space
    imgpoints = [] # 2d points in image plane.

    for image in images:
        frame = cv2.imread(image)
        # height, width, channels = frame.shape # get image parameters
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, chessboard_size, None)   # Find the chess board corners
        if ret:                                                                         # if corners were found
            objpoints.append(objp)
            corners2 = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray, corners, (11, 11), (-1, -1), criteria)    # refine corners
            imgpoints.append(corners2)                                                  # add to corner array

            if show:
                # Draw and display the corners
                frame = cv2.drawChessboardCorners(frame, chessboard_size, corners2, ret)
                cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
                cv2.waitKey(100)

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()             # close open windows
    return objpoints, imgpoints, gray.shape[::-1]

# perform undistortion on provided image
def undistort(image, mtx, dist):
    img = cv2.imread(image, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    image = os.path.splitext(image)[0]
    h, w = img.shape[:2]
    newcameramtx, _ = cv2.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(mtx, dist, (w, h), 1, (w, h))
    dst = cv2.undistort(img, mtx, dist, None, newcameramtx)
    return dst

# draw the provided points on the image
def drawPoints(img, pts, colors):
    for pt, color in zip(pts, colors):
        cv2.circle(img, tuple(pt[0]), 5, color, -1)

# draw the provided lines on the image
def drawLines(img, lines, colors):
    _, c, _ = img.shape
    for r, color in zip(lines, colors):
        x0, y0 = map(int, [0, -r[2]/r[1]])
        x1, y1 = map(int, [c, -(r[2]+r[0]*c)/r[1]])
        cv2.line(img, (x0, y0), (x1, y1), color, 1)

if __name__ == '__main__':

 # undistort our chosen images using the left and right camera and distortion matricies
    imgL = undistort("2L/2L34.bmp", mtxL, distL)
    imgR = undistort("2R/2R34.bmp", mtxR, distR)
    imgL = cv2.cvtColor(imgL, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
    imgR = cv2.cvtColor(imgR, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

    # use get corners to get the new image locations of the checcboard corners (undistort will have moved them a little)
    _, imgpointsL, _ = getCorners(["2L34_undistorted.bmp"], chessboard_size, show=False)
    _, imgpointsR, _ = getCorners(["2R34_undistorted.bmp"], chessboard_size, show=False)

    # get 3 image points of interest from each image and draw them
    ptsL = np.asarray([imgpointsL[0][0], imgpointsL[0][10], imgpointsL[0][20]])
    ptsR = np.asarray([imgpointsR[0][5], imgpointsR[0][15], imgpointsR[0][25]])
    drawPoints(imgL, ptsL, colors[3:6])
    drawPoints(imgR, ptsR, colors[0:3])

    # find epilines corresponding to points in right image and draw them on the left image
    epilinesR = cv2.computeCorrespondEpilines(ptsR.reshape(-1, 1, 2), 2, F)
    epilinesR = epilinesR.reshape(-1, 3)
    drawLines(imgL, epilinesR, colors[0:3])

    # find epilines corresponding to points in left image and draw them on the right image
    epilinesL = cv2.computeCorrespondEpilines(ptsL.reshape(-1, 1, 2), 1, F)
    epilinesL = epilinesL.reshape(-1, 3)
    drawLines(imgR, epilinesL, colors[3:6])

    # combine the corresponding images into one and display them
    combineSideBySide(imgL, imgR, "epipolar_lines", save=True)
```

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: What is inside the chessboard_size variable?

Comment: @Stigma the number of squares on the chessboard pattern, as a tuple. In my example it is `(11,7)`.